# Converter programa para outra codificação no java Ex:(UTF-8 para ansi)

Tags: java, eclipse, codificação-de-caracteres

Boa tarde pessoal, meu código do nada passou pra uma codificação diferente, que acredito ser UTF-8, na hora de executar o código acontece o seguinte erro:

```
   unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

Não há como passar na mão cada parte do código, pois deu erro em mais de 200 palavras. Alguém possui alguma solução?

Já tentei colocar

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso estiver usando o Eclipse, 
- Clica com o direito do mouse em cima do projeto > 
- Properties (Propriedades), 
- Na primeira aba que abrir já estará selecionado o "Resource" (Recursos), 
- Tem um label com o nome "Text file enconding"
- verifica qual está setado e para qual você precisa alterar.

Comment: Já tentei marcar UTF-8 aí também e por padrão vem ANSI, mas não funcionou. :/